# Unable to send more than 1000 variables through url

Tags: php, mysql, search, server

I had a search form and its result is stored in array and passed it through url to the page wish to be displayed.Now when below 1000 items to be searched its works well otherwise lead to internal server error.
is there any other methods like url encryption i can do to solve internal error?
please help me to avoid the internal server error
my code is as follows

```
$cfinalarray = array_intersect($clarray1, $clarray2, $clarray3,       $clarray4,  $clarray5, $clarray6, $clarray7, $clarray8, $clarray9, $clarray10, $clarray12, $clarray13, $clarray14, $clarray15, $clarray16, $clarray17, $clarray18, $clarray19, $clarray20, $clarray22, $clarray23, $clarray24, $clarray25, $clarray26);
                if (count($cfinalarray) > 0) {
                    $arrayc = array_values($cfinalarray);
                    arsort($arrayc);
                    $ab = http_build_query($arrayc);
                    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
                    header("Location: http://example.com/a/b?$ab");
                } else {
                    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
                    header("Location: http://example.com/a/b?search=noresult");
                }
```

result is like this:http://example.com/a/b?2=1120&1=1077&0=1046

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the ini setting 'max_input_vars', which defaults to 1000.  http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php

Answer (score 0):

Check your `php.ini` file and change this line.

```
max_input_vars = 1000
```

1000 means maximum input value, you can change it to what you want. If you don't know how to edit php.ini file please follow this instructions:

1 - Login as root on SSH.
2 - open php.ini file with `nano` or `pico`
(If you're using cPanel, it's `# nano /usr/local/lib/php.ini`)
3 - Press CTRL + W(If using Mac OS press CNTRL + W) and type "max_input_vars"
4 - Then change the value and press CTRL + X to exit and save before exit.

That's all!

Comment: Thanks.Daniz & rawb.Ii have already done that.converted it to 5000 still the issue existed.

Comment: Ok than, please check your website's web folder and inspect inside of .htaccess and php.ini(if there) files. May be you can find max_input_vars value inside of that files. Also please increase max_execution_time and max_input_time values, than restart your web server.

Comment: Hi Daniz,phi.ini file is there.its look like this

max_execution_time = 30     ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
max_input_time = 60 ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
max_input_vars = 5000
memory_limit = 512M      ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (32MB)

Comment: .htaceess file contains # To set your custom php.ini, add the following line to this file:
# suphp_configpath /home/yourusername/path/to/php.ini                       # php_value mbstring.func_overload 4 # Required for PWSB support.     Please do not uncomment this line. 

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/404.php

suPHP_ConfigPath /home/example/public_html                                 Options -MultiViews
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

Comment: Which php.ini file did you edit? On your web root or server's main php.ini? You should edit both.

Comment: Actually yesterday i contacted my server team they have done this for me.but when i check web root php.ini i saw two like this         max_input_vars = 1000                                                                 max_input_vars = 5000

Comment: Delete one of them and make 1000 to what you want. Probably you don't have root access, so contact your server admin to done it. Problems occurs because of that conflict.

Comment: Okay Daniz...Let me do so and so thankful for your time and effort...Thank you so much...Let me try

Comment: Hi Deniz....I have done so with help of server team.still issue is there.Can you please look at my .htacess code if there is any error...or do i check anything else...?

Comment: Can you add this line on your .htaccess file?

max_input_vars = 50000

Comment: Sure...Is it below all lines?Is a ; required at the end of max_input_vars = 50000

Comment: I added it.It leads to internal server error in all pages

Comment: OK than, delete it. Sorry, I don't have another way to fix it.